# How do I move Delphi XE packages and settings to another user?

Tags: delphi, settings, package, delphi-xe

We have set up a new (template) development machine with among other things Delphi XE including a large number of third-party and internal packages, and intend to make a number of clones of this computer for the developers in our team. Note that we are not trying to bypass licensing, we (re-) activate/register Windows, Office, Delphi XE etc. after cloning. My problem is that when I am logged on (as myself) to the clone that will be my own machine, Delphi shows none of the packages we installed (i.e. on the the template machine, using a local Administrator account). Is there anyway I can find and copy/move the Delphi settings from the local administrator to my own user account, so that packages and other settings are the same as we set them up on the template machine before cloning?

Comment: Delphi really needs to have a more portable configuration.  It shouldn't take all day to set up Delphi on a new PC.  Most of the hassle is with 3rd-party libraries, but it seems like a smart tool could find all registered components and zip them all up, with source, including registry entries, and then smartly re-locate and re-register everything on the other end.  Of course, a truly "portable" configuration would be ideal. i.e run nicely on a PortableApps.Com USB stick.

Comment: I was complaining about Delphi's lack of portable configuration, to a Visual C++  developer, and he said, it's not so great for them either. Apparently Java/Eclipse people are used to portable workspaces, but the last time I set up a Java app, it had a few days worth of workstation setup involved in it too.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but we are having the exact same issue with DXE. @Magnus, did you ever figure out why the components would not compile after you dropped them on the form? Did you ever successfully get your application to compile for all users? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I'd try to export the relevant registry keys - something like `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known Packages` for D2007 (probably `..\Embarcadero\..` for XE). You can (carefully!) edit the `*.reg` file and re-import it.

Comment: I exported the entire Embarcadero key for the Administrator, and then imported this file when logged on as myself, and it worked to some extent: I get problems with some specific 3rd-party packages, probably related to how they are installed. I will continue to investigate this. A note: when i tried to edit the registry file before importing it, I got some strange error messages from the registry editor. But the changes I made to some paths was probably not vital, you can easily set e.g. default project path afterwards from within Delphi.

Comment: I solved some of the problems you saw with external packages at startup of Delphi, and disabled another package so that Delphi now starts without errors. Everything looks OK (I see all packages installed), but as soon as I try to drop an external component (I tried components from several different packages) onto a form and compile, Delphi says it can't find the unit that defines this component. I checked the Library Path and it looks OK. Any clues as to why this happens would be much appreciated.

Comment: @sse: You commented on my answer, not on Magnus' question. I'm not sure if he'll get notified of your comment this way.