# Transfer Delphi 2009 projects to another PC

Tags: delphi, migration, delphi-2009, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate Delphi or clone Delphi registry settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140013/how-to-migrate-delphi-or-clone-delphi-registry-settings)

I am starting to learn Delphi 2009. I have been given access to an old Tech's PC (Windows XP) where he has developed a few projects on Delphi '09 and I would like to migrate these projects to my new PC (Windows 7). I have used cnPack to migrate / transfer what I could across PC's, but there are dependencies (I believe plugins) that I cannot locate when attempting to run the older projects on my new PC.

Does anybody know of the simplest method to transfer anything and everything from Delphi '09 from Windows XP to Windows 7?

Comment: related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943311/how-do-i-move-delphi-xe-packages-and-settings-to-another-user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140013/how-to-migrate-delphi-or-clone-delphi-registry-settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023353/how-do-i-back-up-and-restore-my-delphi-settings

Comment: Oh, my... D2009... such a buggy think. One unwanted advice - do not use generics with dynamic types like strings, interfaces and arrays. And better not at all. Also i'd avoid multithreading - to my experience D2009 debugger just dies on MT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory:

when I was working in Delphi, we managed to put together one simple method so that all of us had the same packages installed. It involved some repository containing the libraries and some registry files that we were supposed to load into our registry. It worked fine as we were all under Windows XP.

However, AFAIK, the registry entries under W7 are slightly different.

You could, however, ask someone to make an identical copy of the WinXP and run it as a virtual machine on your W7.

Comment: Not as smooth as I'd like, but ended up using this method. Instead of trying to find out all the repositories, then getting my hands on them, I just download Virtual PC for Windows 7 and cloned my XP PC.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to install all the required plugins on the new PC. This is also a great time to make a list of them including used versions and vendors. You will thank yourself for that later.

An other option is to manually install all the components, but you have to be 100% sure you have all the files.

Comment: Thanks for that information. 
What would the difference be between install and manual install?

Comment: Install == use an installer, manual == copy files yourself and register the components yourself.